# VueJS: Use the $router object outside it's scope

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

A while back I was playing with `vue-router` and had something working like:

```
routes: [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home,
        title: 'Home'
        icon: 'some font awesome icon here'
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        name: 'about',
        title: 'About',
        component: () => import('../pages/About.vue'),
        icon: 'some other font awesome class'
    },

    ...
```

Please notice the `title` and the `icon` properties. Somehow I was able to access those from one of my components.

Now I cannot seem to make it work.

I have tried `this.$route` which gives me the current route, but I do not have those additional properties.

From what I remember I didn't use `props`.
If it makes any difference, I would like to get those sent into a vuex store instance.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [meta](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html#route-meta-fields) property for this:

```
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
        title: 'Home'
        icon: 'some font awesome icon here'
    }
},
```

You can then access this inside your components like:

```
this.$route.meta.title;
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [route meta fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) for this. Something like this:

```
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        title: 'Home',
        icon: 'some font awesome icon here',
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: About,
      meta: {
        title: 'About',
        icon: 'some other font awesome class',
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using router `props` like :

```js
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    props : true // now you can bind props
}
```

Then when you want to navigate to a route dynamically :

```js
this.$router.push({
  name: 'home',
  params: {
    icon: 'some icon here',
    title: 'some title'
  }
})
```

on your component :

```
props : ['icon','title']
```